# How to apply a certain function on all the combinations along a dimension of two tensors?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am trying to achieve something like this in torch.

I have two tensors of shapes `[X, 4]` and `[Y, 4]`. this 4s are basically 4 coordinates of something. So for each combination of `X` and `Y` (2 vectors of length 4), I want to apply some function (elementwise average for example), and form result of the shape `[X, Y, 4]`.

How to do this?

By elementwise average, I mean this operation,

```
[2 4 6 8] OP [8 6 4 2] = [5 5 5 5]
```

But it can be any arbitrary operation.

N.B. I was able to solve it using loops, but searching for a vectorized solution.

Comment: it really depends on your OP. Is there an specific operator you have in mind or do you need it to work for ANY op? There are some builtin functions in Numpy for some OPs. For a custom OP it would be a bit of extra work.

Comment: @Ehsan actually this 4 are the coordinates of a bounding box. Let's consider, for each of that combination, I want to apply a function,  as my operation isn't trivial. (IOU for example). But yes, it doesn't have to support just any operation, it will be a specific one

Comment: is your custom function vectorized? does it support `axis` argument?

Comment: no, right now it doesn't support axis argument.

Comment: I think depending on your function, might be easier to start there. Once it supports axis argument, you can pretty much implement anything with it. Please check out my answer for example.

Comment: Please check out my answer for one way of implementing custom functions without axis argument. You can check its performance by timing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer depends on the function. For example, for element wise mean:

```
np.mean([x[:,None,:],y[None,...]], axis=0)
```

or for einsum:

```
np.einsum('ij,kj->ikj',x,y)
```

or for summation:

```
x[:,None,:]+y[None,...]
```

And if you implement your **CUSTOM function** properly (**elementwise**), you can use broadcasting to do the job using this:

```
np.frompyfunc(myfunc,2,1)(x[:,None,:],y[None,...])
```

sample:

```
x = array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])

y = array([[100, 101, 102, 103],
       [104, 105, 106, 107],
       [108, 109, 110, 111]])

#np.mean([x[:,None,:],y[None,...]], axis=0)
array([[[50, 51, 52, 53],
        [52, 53, 54, 55],
        [54, 55, 56, 57]],

       [[52, 53, 54, 55],
        [54, 55, 56, 57],
        [56, 57, 58, 59]]])

#np.einsum('ij,kj->ikj',x,y)
array([[[  0, 101, 204, 309],
        [  0, 105, 212, 321],
        [  0, 109, 220, 333]],

       [[400, 505, 612, 721],
        [416, 525, 636, 749],
        [432, 545, 660, 777]]])


#x[:,None,:]+y[None,...]
array([[[100, 102, 104, 106],
        [104, 106, 108, 110],
        [108, 110, 112, 114]],

       [[104, 106, 108, 110],
        [108, 110, 112, 114],
        [112, 114, 116, 118]]])

def myfunc(x, y):
    return x+y
#np.frompyfunc(myfunc,2,1)(x[:,None,:],y[None,...]) 

array([[[100, 102, 104, 106],
        [104, 106, 108, 110],
        [108, 110, 112, 114]],

       [[104, 106, 108, 110],
        [108, 110, 112, 114],
        [112, 114, 116, 118]]], dtype=object)
```